# Update only one record with Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Firstly, I will show what I want to do.

I want check if user has more than one record:

```
WHERE 'from_user_id' == '$id'
```

When query `return > 0`, I want update only ONE record `where 'from_user_id' == '$id'`,

I dont care about order, It can be last or first record, but I have to update only one record.

Here is part of my model:

```
public function get_bonuses() {
    if ($this->db->where('from_user_id', $this->user_id())->from($this->reff_table)->count_all_results()>0 ) {
        $this->db->where('from_user_id', $this->user_id());
        $this->db->update($this->reff_table, array('used' => '1'));
        return true;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

It works fine but I want update only one record :<

I hope anyone will help me.
Regards

----- EDIT
SOLVED - I'm so stupid but I needed to look from the other side to my code :)
Here is working code:

```
if ($this->db->where(array('from_user_id' =>$this->user_id(), 'used' => '0' ))->from($this->reff_table)->count_all_results()>0 ) { $this->db->where(array('from_user_id' =>$this->user_id(), 'used' => '0' ))->limit(1); $this->db->update($this->reff_table, array('used' => '1')); return true;
```

Comment: Lol, I'm so stupid. 
Here is solution:

Comment: if ($this->db->where(array('from_user_id' =>$this->user_id(), 'used' => '0' ))->from($this->reff_table)->count_all_results()>0 )
        {
          $this->db->where(array('from_user_id' =>$this->user_id(), 'used' => '0' ))->limit(1);
          $this->db->update($this->reff_table, array('used' => '1'));
               return true;

Comment: You can edit your post with the correct query

Comment: @Jakon89: Instead of posting the correct answer as a comment, answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update any one record from result, simply limit the query where you check count to 1 & grab its unique id (primary key) and update that row.